Design helm chart to create multiple service accounts
I am attempting to create a helm chart template that will create multiple service accounts. The reason being, I need one service account to authenticate my pod the other service account for the workload managed identity. When I run the helm chart below, I don't get the expected results.
Below is the values.yaml:
`serviceAccounts:
  - name: SA1
    annotations:
      meta.helm.sh/release-name: "SA1"
      meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: "somenamespace"
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: SA1
      app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
      app.kubernetes.io/name: SA1
      app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.0.0"
      helm.sh/chart: SA1-1.0.0
      version: "1.0.0"
 
  - name: SA2
    annotations:
      azure.workload.identity/client-id: XXXXXXX
    labels:
      azure.workload.identity/use: "true"`

And the service-account helm chart template:
`{{- range .Values.serviceAccounts }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: {{ .name }}
  namespace: {{ index .annotations "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" }}
  annotations:
    {{- toYaml .annotations | nindent 4 }}
  labels:
    {{- toYaml .labels | nindent 4 }}
{{- end }}
 `

The problem is, SA2 gets created during deployment but SA1 does not. Can someone please help me understand why this is?

You should add separate dashes at the top of every API resource like,
{{- range .Values.serviceAccounts }}
--- # This separator line is essential
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: {{ .name }}
  namespace: {{ index .annotations "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" }}
  annotations:
    {{- toYaml .annotations | nindent 4 }}
  labels:
    {{- toYaml .labels | nindent 4 }}
{{- end }}

